# Getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error while creating new react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Below is the error message;

```
Aborting installation.

  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules

Deleting generated file... package.json

Deleting firstapp / from D:\Atom Projects\NewProject
Done.
```

I have checked the path environmental variable path, it seems to be perfect.

Comment: Spaces in folder namess often cause problems with command-line. I suggest that you create a folder without any spaces in the name and try again.

Comment: Thanku..I tried with folder without any spaces..facing the same issue. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the "Ansicon Entries" in the Registry

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun**

helped me solving the issue. I followed the solution posted in
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/121